# Keyboard doesn't disappear

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

While using UITextField in objective c, keyboard appears, after typing some figure I wanna move to another Textfield or button but neither the cursor removes from text field nor the key board disappears. Wat should i do?

```
tempTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
tempTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
tempTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
tempTextField.placeholder = @"";
tempTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tempTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;  

tempTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault; 
tempTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
tempTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
tempTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;   
[ tempTextField setEnabled: YES ];
self.txtAirportName = tempTextField;
txtAirportName.delegate = self;
[tempTextField release];
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the [`resignFirstResponder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of `UIResponder`, which [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) inherits from:

```
[tempTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Classic. I think just about everyone misses this. I know I did when I first started with iPhone development.

Comment: It is a little strange. *Becoming* firstResponder is automatic (well, when the user touches the textField) but when they touch outside, it doesn't resignFirstResponder. It does feel a little unintuitive, I agree.

Comment: That's probably why everyone gets caught by the keyboard. If both acquiring and resigning were automatic or if both were manual, I don't think it would be an issue.

Comment: Funny thing though, [I did that exactly to customize  UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6866932/434423) but never disappeared.